# How can I quicksort a two dimension array by a specific cell?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, quicksort, qsort

I have got a 2d array and I would like to quicksort it with the given qsort() function in C++:

```
unsigned work[N][3];
```

I would like to sort the "work" array by the third index... so if `work[i]` goes before `work[j]` if `work[i][2]>work[j][2]`.

I know I would need to use a function to compare it, but I have no inkling how to do that.

**edit:**
If I would do the following, would that help:

```
unsigned work[3][N];
qsort(work[2], N, sizeof(unsigned), compare);
```

And compare would be the following:

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return(*(unsigned*)a-*(unsigned*)b);
}
```

?

Comment: Please clarify: Is this C, or C++? If you're working with C++, the solution is easy: Don't use C arrays but C++ data containers, and `std::sort()` instead of `qsort()`. `std::sort()` is quicker, too...

Comment: I am really a newbie at programming, I am trying to use C++, so if you could give me some examples of the mentioned C++ data containers I would look after them.

Comment: *"If I would do the following, would that help"* - No, it wouldn't. Have you even read the answers?

Comment: *"I am trying to use C++"* - So why is your question then retaged to *C*? Now once and for all, do you want to use *C* or *C++* (and please don't say *C/C++*, that's even worse than the current confusion madness).

Comment: @DevSolar Did you just totally change the question by retagging it to a totally different language (contrary to the OP's comments)?

Comment: @ChristianRau: All the code provided, plus the question title, spoke "C", not "C++". Reverted the re-tag according to OP's comment.

Comment: @ChristianRau "No, it wouldn't." Yes, actually it is working fine, I just did it. I tagged the question as C++ as you can see it at: "I have got a 2d array which and I would like to quicksort it with the given qsort() function in C++" first line in the question. Yes, I have read the anwsers but I am looking after some C++ code. You may say it's C++ but If i am right it is as C++ as C...

Comment: @nábob *"Yes, actually it is working fine"* - If you used the code from your edit, then, no, it didn't work, whatever you experienced was either luck (which is not a rare thing when invoking UB, though first you should have ignored a whole bunch of compiler warnings *and errors*, don't know how that was even possible) or you didn't notice the error (which unfortunately didn't result in a program crash). But the code from your edit **is wrong** and there is no way to interpret it as working in any way.

Comment: @ChristianRau Yes, actually the comparator function is this: `int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return(*(unsigned*)a-*(unsigned*)b);
}`

Comment: @nábob Aaah! That makes much more sense (well, at least it should compile). But still this won't work, since with your `qsort`-call you don't sort the first 2 elements and, even worse, your element size (third argument) doesn't match. Currently you interpret this `unsigned[N][3]` array in memory as an `unsigned[N]` array starting at `work[2][0]`. So you only just sort the first third of your array and that in a wrong way.

Comment: @ChristianRau unsigned[N][3] =/= unsigned[3][N]

Comment: @nabob Wait, hah indeed! Well, ok now I see that it indeed works, sorry for overlooking that! But now you have changed the whole layout of your data structure, just to be able to use your own `std::qsort` version (while those from the existing answers work perfectly correct with your previous data structure). If this is no problem and the reversed array structure fits better to the rest of your code than your previous version, then well, this is indeed a solution. Though it somehow invalidates the prerequisits of the question, doesn't it.

Comment: @nábob So yes, it indeed helps, but neither is it neccessary, unless the rest of your code not shown also profits from this totally new data structure.

Comment: @nábob Wait, no, it still doesn't work. It sorts the third sub-array, but it doesn't touch the first parts of the whole array of arrays. So the sorting will confuse the correspondence of the individual 3-component data elements. Say before sorting you have `(1,2,3), (4,5,6)` (though layed out as `(1,4) (2,5) (3,6)` in the new array). Now after sorting you won't have `(4,5,6), (1,2,3)`, but `(1,2,6) (4,5,3)` since you didn't just sort **by** the 3rd component, but **only** the 3rd component, which is a semantic totally different from your original question.

Comment: @ChristianRau _"Though it somehow invalidates the prerequisits of the question, doesn't it."_ Yes, you are right, and please remember that I really appreciate your help but I would like the easiest way to solve my problem and the anwsers below are a bit difficult for me :)

Comment: @ChristianRau Thank you, you are right it really confuses everything...

Comment: @nábob Well, in the end you can just use your `compare` function with my `std::qsort`-call, which wouldn't be any more complicated than your code. But switch `a` and `b` in the compare function, since you want to sort them in ascending order. It won't get any much less complicated since, well, `std::qsort` doesn't have that obvious an interface, being a relic of *C*. In fact dropping *C* and using proper *C++* containers would simplify much (and not only sorting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the short answer would be to not use [`std::qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) at all, but [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). But unfortunately the latter won't work, since `unsigned int[3]` is not assignable. So here's the easiest `std::qsort` solution.

First we define a custom comparator function:

```
// return -1 if a before b, 1 if after, 0 if equal
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const unsigned int *arg1 = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned int*>(a);
    const unsigned int *arg2 = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned int*>(b);
    if(arg1[2] > arg2[2])
        return -1;
    if(arg1[2] < arg2[2])
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Which we then use to sort the array. Keep in mind that `work` is an array of arrays, and thus `work[0]` is an array of 3 `unsigned int`s, there's no pointer indirection involved in any way. So it's perfectly suited for being sorted by `std::qsort`:

```
std::qsort(work, sizeof(work)/sizeof(work[0]), sizeof(work[0]), compare);
```

By the way, the third element is indexed with `2`, since we usually start to count at `0` in C++ (and many other programming languages).

**EDIT:** Though, the best solution would indeed be to drop this array of arrays and use something more suited to C++, like a `std::vector` of `std::array<unsigned int,3>`s (or any other datastructure that fits a bit more to the actual context):

```
typedef std::array<unsigned int,3> uint3;
std::vector<uint3> work(N);
```

Which can then be sorted with a simple:

```
std::sort(std::begin(work), std::end(work), 
          [](const uint3 &a, const uint3 &b) { return a[2] > b[2]; });
```

Or, if you don't have C++11 (though in this case you won't have `std::array` either and need to start thinking about a resonable datastructure apart from a mere 3-array):

```
struct compare
{
    bool operator()(const uint3 &a, const uint3 &b) const
    {
        return a[2] > b[2];
    }
};

std::sort(work.begin(), work.end(), compare());
```

As a bonus to much clearer code, you also most probably get a slight performance boost of `std::sort` over `std::qsort`.

Comment: What about the following: `unsigned work[3][N];
qsort(work[3], N, sizeof(unsigned), compare);`

Comment: @nábob No, that's wrong. The first argument is the start of the array, which is just `work`, decaying to a pointer, `work[3]` would be the 3rd element. The second argument is the number of elements, which is the size of the array (`sizeof(work)`) divided by the size of one element (`sizeof(work[0])`) (ok, which is indeed `N` in the end). The third argument is the size of a single element, which is `sizeof(work[0])` (and actually `3*sizeof(unsigned int)`). Why come up with your own arguments to the function if you don't know how to call it (in which case you wouldn't have posted a question)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can `qsort()` this. `qsort()` works by taking a required *linear* block of "stuff", partitioning it into uniform sized chunks where *you* specify the size (in bytes), and feeding you the base address of each block partition for comparison.

First, determine the size you need. It should be obvious the "things" you're sorting are array *rows* three elements wide. Second, write a comparator that can accept the base address of two such things as pointers, in our case, a simple pointer will work, as it nicely peels off the outer array dimension. Finally, the actually comparison will be three elements deep (`p[2]` to be precise) off each pointer `p` we're given:

So lets flesh the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <time.h>

static const size_t ROWSIZE = 3;

static void print_array(int rows, int ar[rows][ROWSIZE])
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<rows;++i)
    {
        for (j=0; j<ROWSIZE; printf("%d ", ar[i][j++]));
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// compare function
static int compare_row(const void* left, const void* right)
{
    const int *ileft = left, *iright = right;
    return ileft[ROWSIZE-1] - iright[ROWSIZE-1];
}

int main()
{
    int ar[10][ROWSIZE] = {0}, i;

    // fill with random junk from 10 to 99
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    for (i=0;i<ROWSIZE * sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0]); ++i)
        ar[i/ROWSIZE][i%ROWSIZE] = 10 + (rand() % 90);

    // print prior to sort.
    print_array(sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0]), ar);

    // send to qsort
    qsort(ar, sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0]), sizeof(ar[0]), compare_row);

    // print again after sort.
    print_array(sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0]), ar);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
50 14 23 
69 81 93 
30 72 18 
26 49 29 
51 87 58 
18 74 40 
26 61 26 
43 80 27 
27 61 34 
13 66 89 

30 72 18 
50 14 23 
26 61 26 
43 80 27 
26 49 29 
27 61 34 
18 74 40 
51 87 58 
13 66 89 
69 81 93
```

Comment: What if my comparator function body is: `const int (*ileft)[ROWSIZE] = (const int (*)[ROWSIZE])left, (*iright)[ROWSIZE] = (const int (*)[ROWSIZE])right;
    return (*ileft)[ROWSIZE-1] - (*iright)[ROWSIZE-1];` ?